# How i get free disk space storage?

Tags: ubuntu, memory, storage

I am a new linux user and I have to install some packages that required me about 14GB storage.
How can I find out my storage? My device is a Nvidia Jetson TX2 that runs Ubuntu OS.

Comment: With `df` (`df -h`), but it depends on how your disk is partitioned and where the space is required. It's not clear whether all space is required in a single partition (like under `/usr`) or whether space will also be use elsewhere (e.g. in `/home` or `/var`).

Comment: I really don't know, I just follow up a tutorial that uses a lot of sudo apt get install commands. I run df -h command, and I got some Filesystem like /dev/mmcblk0p1, none, tmpfs, and so on that are mapped to a mounted point. How can i find out if I have available the necessary storage. This is the tutorial that I follow : https://qengineering.eu/install-tensorflow-2.3.1-on-jetson-nano.html ( for c++ )

Comment: LoL, reading the title made me think that you want more storage space for free (that would be nice if it existed) but you only asked for the free space that you have available :p

Comment: @user488375: `df -h /` to see the available space in the root partition. To find out what directories are using your space run `shopt -s dotglob` and then `du -hs *` to see how much space each subdirectory is using (the `du` command will be show for the first execution, but it caches the results so future runs are considerably faster).

Answer (score 1):

Use this command to find a specific size of a folder

```
du -bsh
```